# wicked pdf styles not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am unable to get the wicked pdf styles working. I have tried several options as seen in stack overflow questions and over the web, with no luck. Here is the code I have -

Controller -

```
 format.pdf do
     html = render_to_string(template: 'orders/showPDF.html.erb', layout: 'order_pdf')
     document_data = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html)
     send_data(document_data, filename: 'filename', type:  application/pdf')
 end
```

layout - order_pdf.pdf.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
           <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
           <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag("application"), media: "all" %>
           <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag("app/orders/showPDF"), media: "all"  %>
           <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
           <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
           <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' -%>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="orderContent">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

I have also added `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js application.scss app/orders/showPDF.scss)` to assets.rb

ShowPDF.scss has all the styles that I want to include. If I set the extension of the layout as 'order_pdf.html.erb', I see the error 'undefined mixin grid-container'. So, I renamed it to 'order_pdf.pdf.erb', but don't see any styles applied. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for debug, try print to console the `html` string and check if paths generated by `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` are ok.

Comment: I do not see any reference to the stylesheet link when I print html string. 
Could it be because its an .scss file?

Comment: Looking at the gem source, it seems to append `.css` https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/2b429c75b235e1df9fc4a29c1b96dbb77e2d9726/lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb